# Website's traffic increases suddenly, found static.reverse.softlayer.com in visitors list

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My website's traffic increases suddenly in a high rate. I checked my visitors list and found **static.reverse.softlayer.com**. This has been happening for last few weeks but I did not notice it then. I searched about **static.reverse.softlayer.com** and found horrible stories. How can I prevent anything like **static.reverse.softlayer.com** (if it is liable) which increases traffic.

I am also worried about my website's security. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a company which creates just a lot of traffic, block it via .htaccess

```
deny from 5.10.83.0/25
```

To add some information: the IP-Range 5.10.83.0 - 5.10.83.127 is owned by softlayer.com, but used by ahrefs.com. And this is a SEO service which checks websites for money or smthg, im not rly sure, but the best decision you can do is block iz.

Comment: In my visitor's list, IP address of static.reverse.softlayer.com shows 184.172.185.191. Should I block only this IP address or IP address range given by you?

Comment: Thats strange, i usually only block my range and have no trouble with it. But if it shows another IP, you should block that one. If you want to be completely safe, just block both.

Comment: Thanks I will try it. One strange thing is, there is no referring URL in my visitor's list regarding this static.reverse.softlayer.com. So I am unable to find out which of my web pages were visited.

Comment: You might want to add 37.58.100.0/25 as well. They apparently got new IP addresses.

Comment: Oh god, these guys are really annoying. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Other Softlayer IPs

```
50.22.0.0/15
50.97.0.0/16
66.228.112.0/20
67.228.0.0/16
74.86.0.0/16
75.126.0.0/16
173.192.0.0/15
174.36.0.0/15
208.43.0.0/16
208.101.0.0/18
108.168.128.0/17
159.253.128.0/19
```

It's up to you to restrict them all or not.