# How to prevent bandwidth theft of my website and why I find my website IP address sometimes dedicated & sometimes shared

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ip, bandwidth, hotlinking

I think someone is stealing bandwidth of my website. To prevent this I enabled **hotlink**. But there are only extensions related to image. How can I protect my other files with extensions like **.php** or **.asp**? When I add **.php** or **.asp** extensions, I was unable to access in my website.

Another thing is, I found, in my cpanel IP address of my website sometimes appears as **dedicated** and sometimes as **shared**. Why is this happening?

I found **static.reverse.softlayer.com** in my visitors list. But which web pages it visited are not displayed. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can only protect secondary material from hotlinking, for example images, Javascript files and CSS files. Because those are fetched from a page in your site, the server can determine if they are used correctly or not.

If you try to keep primary material (e.g. the actual web pages) from being hotlinked, you are actually keeping them from being fetched at all. Any resource that you want to be available directly can't be locked down that way.

Comment: So, what should I do to prevent bandwidth theft & what is the reason of changing the status sometimes dedicated or sometimes shared of the IP address of website?

Comment: Requesting web pages to steal bandwith doesn't make sense. This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901039/websites-traffic-increases-suddenly-found-static-reverse-softlayer-com-in-visi Regarding the cpanel issue I don't have anything to contribute. Sounds like it's confused, as a dedicated IP address isn't something that just changes on it's own.